# USB touch screen HID descriptor for 2 contact identifier

Tags: c, multi-touch, hid

Currently i am working on USB touch screen HID descriptors(custom HID descriptor),on STM32f4 board.
For that, I have implemented a HID descriptor for single contact identifier(single finger touch) and which is working for me.But, my requirement is for Multi touch finger.
So, i am modifying my single touch finger HID to multi touch HID.In this case,i have added some report for 2nd finger.

This is my Report descriptor for 2 fingers...

```
0x05, 0x0D,        // Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x09, 0x04,        // Usage (Touch Screen)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x09, 0x55,        //   Usage (0x55)
0x25, 0x03,        //   Logical Maximum (3)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0x54,        //   Usage (0x54)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x09, 0x22,        //   Usage (Finger)
0xA1, 0x02,        //   Collection (Logical)
0x09, 0x51,        //     Usage (0x51)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x09, 0x42,        //     Usage (Tip Switch)
0x09, 0x32,        //     Usage (In Range)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //     Logical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x01,        //     Report Size (1)
0x95, 0x02,        //     Report Count (2)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x95, 0x06,        //     Report Count (6)
0x81, 0x03,        //     Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //     Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x30,        //     Usage (X)
0x09, 0x31,        //     Usage (Y)
0x16, 0x00, 0x00,  //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0x10, 0x27,  //     Logical Maximum (10000)
0x36, 0x00, 0x00,  //     Physical Minimum (0)
0x46, 0x10, 0x27,  //     Physical Maximum (10000)
0x66, 0x00, 0x00,  //     Unit (None)
0x75, 0x10,        //     Report Size (16)
0x95, 0x02,        //     Report Count (2)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
0x05, 0x0D,        //   Usage Page (Digitizer)
0x09, 0x22,        //   Usage (Finger)
0xA1, 0x02,        //   Collection (Logical)
0x05, 0x0D,        //     Usage Page (Digitizer) 
0x09, 0x51,        //     Usage (0x51)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x09, 0x42,        //     Usage (Tip Switch)
0x09, 0x32,        //     Usage (In Range)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //     Logical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x01,        //     Report Size (1)
0x95, 0x02,        //     Report Count (2)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x95, 0x06,        //     Report Count (6)
0x81, 0x03,        //     Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //     Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x30,        //     Usage (X)
0x09, 0x31,        //     Usage (Y)
0x16, 0x00, 0x00,  //     Logical Minimum (0) 
0x26, 0x10, 0x27,  //     Logical Maximum (10000)
0x66, 0x00, 0x00,  //     Unit (None)
0x75, 0x10,        //     Report Size (16)
0x95, 0x02,        //     Report Count (2)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
0xC0,              // End Collection
```

I am testing this in windows 10 touch lapy,where i have USBlyzer to analyse the data which sending from board to PC.

In the analyzer i am getting like this..
[image]

in the analysis, it shows the same data for finger 1,2, even though i am sending different data.

Here i am attaching how i m sending data..

```
my_buff[0]  = 0x02;  // contact count 

my_buff[1]  = 0x01;  // contact identifier(finger1)
my_buff[2]  = 0x03;  // tip switch and in range
my_buff[3]  = 0x88;  // x axis lsb
my_buff[4]  = 0x13;  // x axis msb
my_buff[5]  = 0x88;  // y axis lsb
my_buff[6]  = 0x13;  // y axis msb

my_buff[7]  = 0x02;  // contact identifier(finger2)
my_buff[8]  = 0x03;  // tip switch and in range
my_buff[9]  = 0x70;  // x axis lsb
my_buff[10] = 0x12;  // x axis msb
my_buff[11] = 0x70;  // y axis lsb
my_buff[12] = 0x12;  // y axis msb

USBD_HID_SendReport (&USB_OTG_dev, 
                     my_buff,
                         13);
```

In this case i am not getting even single touch.But, if i disable tip switch in finger 2 then finger 1 touch is working.

But if i disable finger 1 tip switch, and enable finger 2 tip switch then even i am not getting single touch.

so,please help me where i went wrong.

i don't know whether problem is because of report Descriptor or some other thing..

thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things not quite right with the report descriptor which could confuse the host HID parser (or cause different behaviour across host operating systems), so I would recommend fixing those first including:

- an empty Feature report definition (this could be the real problem)
- logical minimum not specified
- report size too small to accommodate logical maximum value
- forgetting to reset physical units before defining subsequent fields (you can use PUSH and POP for that)

The report descriptor as it stands would be parsed as:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 0D        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000D Digitizer Device Page 
09 04        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0004 Touch Screen (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x000D0004: Page=Digitizer Device Page, Usage=Touch Screen, Type=Application Collection)
09 55          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0055 Contact Count Maximum (Static Value)  
25 03          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x03 (3)  
B1 02          (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000002 ( fields x  bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap  <-- Error: REPORT_SIZE is undefined <-- Error: REPORT_COUNT is undefined <-- Error: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is undefined
09 54          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0054 Contact Count (Dynamic Value)  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap  <-- Error: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is undefined
09 22          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0022 Finger (Logical Collection)  
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x000D0022: Page=Digitizer Device Page, Usage=Finger, Type=Logical Collection)
09 51            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0051 Contact Identifier (Dynamic Value)  
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 8 
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap  <-- Error: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is undefined
09 42            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0042 Tip Switch (Momentary Control)  
09 32            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0032 In Range (Momentary Control)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (2 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 06            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x06 (6) Number of fields  
81 03            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (6 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
16 0000          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x0000 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 16 0000 with 14
26 1027          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x2710 (10000)  
36 0000          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MINIMUM   0x0000 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 36 0000 with 34
46 1027          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x2710 (10000)  
66 0000          (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x0000 No unit (0=None) <-- Redundant: UNIT is already 0x00000000 <-- Info: Consider replacing 66 0000 with 64
75 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field  
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (2 fields x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical  <-- Warning: Physical units are still in effect PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=10000) UNIT(0x,EXP=0)
05 0D          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000D Digitizer Device Page 
09 22          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0022 Finger (Logical Collection)  
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x000D0022: Page=Digitizer Device Page, Usage=Finger, Type=Logical Collection)
05 0D            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000D Digitizer Device Page <-- Redundant: USAGE_PAGE is already 0x000D
09 51            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0051 Contact Identifier (Dynamic Value)  
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap  <-- Error: REPORT_SIZE (8) is too small for LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (10000) which needs 14 bits.
09 42            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0042 Tip Switch (Momentary Control)  
09 32            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0032 In Range (Momentary Control)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (2 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 06            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x06 (6) Number of fields  
81 03            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (6 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
16 0000          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x0000 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 16 0000 with 14
26 1027          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x2710 (10000)  
66 0000          (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x0000 No unit (0=None) <-- Redundant: UNIT is already 0x00000000 <-- Info: Consider replacing 66 0000 with 64
75 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field  
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (2 fields x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical  <-- Warning: Physical units are still in effect PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=10000) UNIT(0x,EXP=0)
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application  <-- Warning: Physical units are still in effect PHYSICAL(MIN=0,MAX=10000) UNIT(0x,EXP=0)
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Digitizer Device Page featureReport (Device <-> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: TouchScreen
                                                     // Usage 0x000D0055 Contact Count Maximum, Value =  to 3 <-- Ignored: REPORT_COUNT () is too small
} featureReport_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Digitizer Device Page inputReport (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: TouchScreen
  int8_t   DIG_TouchScreenContactCount;              // Usage 0x000D0054: Contact Count, Value =  to 3
                                                     // Collection: TouchScreen Finger
  int8_t   DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier;   // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value =  to 3
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange : 1;         // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX;                    // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 10000, Physical = Value
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY;                    // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 10000, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_1; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 10000, Physical = Value
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_1 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value x 10000
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_1 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1, Physical = Value x 10000
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_1;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 10000, Physical = Value
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_1;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 10000, Physical = Value
} inputReport_t;
```

Here is another multi-touch report descriptor (using report ids) which may be worth experimenting with:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 0D        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000D Digitizer Device Page 
09 04        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0004 Touch Screen (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x000D0004: Page=Digitizer Device Page, Usage=Touch Screen, Type=Application Collection)
85 54          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x54 (84) 'T'  
09 22          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0022 Finger (Logical Collection)  
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x000D0022: Page=Digitizer Device Page, Usage=Finger, Type=Logical Collection)
09 42            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0042 Tip Switch (Momentary Control)  
14               (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    (0)  
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 32            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0032 In Range (Momentary Control)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 47            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0047 Confidence (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 05            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields  
81 03            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
09 51            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0051 Contact Identifier (Dynamic Value)  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
26 FF7F          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7FFF (32767)  
75 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field  
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical 
05 0D          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000D Digitizer Device Page 
09 22          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0022 Finger (Logical Collection)  
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x000D0022: Page=Digitizer Device Page, Usage=Finger, Type=Logical Collection)
09 42            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0042 Tip Switch (Momentary Control)  
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 32            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0032 In Range (Momentary Control)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 47            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0047 Confidence (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 05            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields  
81 03            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (5 fields x 1 bit) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
09 51            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0051 Contact Identifier (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
26 FF7F          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7FFF (32767)  
75 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field  
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical 
05 0D          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000D Digitizer Device Page 
09 54          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0054 Contact Count (Dynamic Value)  
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
25 08          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x08 (8)  
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 55          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000D0055 Contact Count Maximum (Static Value)  
B1 02          (MAIN)   FEATURE            0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Digitizer Device Page featureReport 54 (Device <-> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x54 (84) 'T'
                                                     // Collection: TouchScreen
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenContactCountMaximum;       // Usage 0x000D0055: Contact Count Maximum, Value = 0 to 8
} featureReport54_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Digitizer Device Page inputReport 54 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x54 (84) 'T'
                                                     // Collection: TouchScreen Finger
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange : 1;         // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence : 1;      // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier;   // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX;                    // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY;                    // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerTipSwitch_1 : 1;     // Usage 0x000D0042: Tip Switch, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerInRange_1 : 1;       // Usage 0x000D0032: In Range, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerConfidence_1 : 1;    // Usage 0x000D0047: Confidence, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenFingerContactIdentifier_1; // Usage 0x000D0051: Contact Identifier, Value = 0 to 1
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerX_1;                  // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 32767
  uint16_t GD_TouchScreenFingerY_1;                  // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 32767
                                                     // Collection: TouchScreen
  uint8_t  DIG_TouchScreenContactCount;              // Usage 0x000D0054: Contact Count, Value = 0 to 8
} inputReport54_t;
```